# How can I make Firefox cache a large image?

Tags: http, https, browser-cache, cache-control

I have issues convincing Firefox 71 to cache a large (>4MB) image. I notice both in developer tools (as being logged) and during normal operations (as per loading delay) that the image is loaded every time the page is accessed.

Although I thought I provided all the necessary response headers, Firefox is not sending `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` request headers.

These are the HTTP headers my server is sending:

```
$ HEAD https:///image.png
200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2020 19:52:20 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "564cd5fb-4484b0"
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 4490416
Content-Type: image/png
Last-Modified: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 19:48:11 GMT
Client-Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2020 19:52:20 GMT
Client-Peer: 
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /CN=
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
```

The web page loads the image via JavaScript:

```
let mapImg = new Image();
mapImg.src = 'image.png';
```

I believe I did everything according to documentation and wonder if I made some wrong combination of response headers, encryption, compression, and loading method?

Comment: If you send exactly the same headers, but for small images, do you still have the same problem or wil ff cache it? I was working with caching and ff like 8 years ago if i remember correct it was also a problem then. Was working in ie, Chrome and safari.

Comment: Good hint! I have replicated the same settings for a smaller image (46kb) and Firefox doesn't even send a request due to the immuatble Cache-Control header. Perhaps there is a limit on sizes of images to be cached in perpetuity to prevent users' caches to be maliciously stuffed with junk?

Comment: The [default value of `browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Mozilla_networking_preferences#Cache) (51200 KB) suggest that a file of that size should not be excluded due to size, although it may only be cached on disk.